# Waiting screen while response is awaited

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a one iframe in which one webservice has opened .A forms is in that web service.After submitting that form my iframe will close.But before closing iframe I want some waiting screen till the form data is submitted at web service and receieved some response from there(like please wait while your operaion is processed).Can any one suggest me some good code snippet or link.I want to do it with jquery.My application is in .net.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Whilst new I can point you towards this topic that I found useful:
[Welcome-loading-page-with-jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955746/welcome-loading-page-with-jquery)

Many Thanks, 
Joel