# how to set jquery when my asp.net page want to load

Tags: asp.net

i want to when my page loading , loading with jquery (progress bar) and when finished, user can see page

Asp.Net with c#

Comment: simply google can give you good answer for this question,and there are multiple same question like this-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955746/welcome-loading-page-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you have to load everything via jquery ajax. And while data is getting loaded, you can show a loading div on the page and hide it when its done.

Sample jquery-ajax function for your reference.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json; Characterset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        // hide loading div
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert("Exception Handling :  \n" + request.responseText);                        
    },
    complete: function () {
       //
    }
});
```

Comment: do u can give me a sample project?

Comment: Ahh, that you have to do it yourself. I can just guide you. You have to load each control using ajax only.

Comment: im new begginer to jquery and asp.net(not Server side) !